# mutidimentional array into single array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm having

```
Array(
      [0] => Array(
        [0] => My Property
        [1] => Array(
            [0] => Tiles Market
            [1] => My Floor
            )
        )
)
```

and i want out as

```
array([0]=>My Property [1] => Tiles Market [2] => My Floor)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: You can use [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php). See my answer and demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156933/mutidimentional-array-into-single-array-in-php/24161016#24161016)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(); // Your array content

$merged_array = array();
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
foreach($ri as $r) {
   array_push($merged_array,$r);
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($merged_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$new_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $old_array);
```

Comment: FYI: this appeared in the low quality posts queue because someone flagged it. Your answer appears plausible, so I presume it is because it is a code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/meeJGALV)**

You can do that with [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) like below;

```
<?php
function MultiToOne($from, &$to) {
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($from));
    foreach($it as $k => $v) {
      $to[] = $v;
    }   
}


$arr = array(
      "0" => array(
        "0" => "My Property",
        "1" => array(
            "0" => "Tiles Market",
            "1" => "My Floor"
            )
        )
);

$myFinalArr = array();
MultiToOne($arr, $myFinalArr);

var_dump($myFinalArr);

?>
```